# Maven maven-dependency-plugin copy-dependencies ignores outputDirectory

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm try to use the maven-dependency-plugin's copy-dependencies goal.
I checked [its official example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) with the snippet below.

My problem is: the dependencies are always copied to 
`target\dependency` folder, even if I specify an `<outputDirectory>` node.

Here is the part of my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
                <configuration>
                      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/aaa</outputDirectory>
                      <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                      <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                      <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>                  
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Question**: What I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to declare the output directory outside of the project? For example: `c:\temp` ?

Comment: How are you invoking Maven? What's the command?

Comment: I tried from eclipse, and from command line. The command is: mvn dependency:copy-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configured an execution of the `maven-dependency-plugin` with a configuration only defined within its scope, hence it will only be picked up by the plugin during a `mvn package` invocation, that is, while performing the `package` phase and the plugin (executions) having a binding to it.

If you invoke the plugin from command line as following:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

It will indeed only use default values, since your configuration will be ignored.

In fact, the default value for the [`outputDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#outputDirectory) option is indeed:

> **Default**: `${project.build.directory}/dependency`

In maven, a plugin configuration can be defined as general configuration (outside of an `execution` section, applied to all executions and to command line invocations) or per execution (within an `execution` section, like in your case).

---

In your case, you probably want the configuration to be valid in both cases, so simply change your plugin section to the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/aaa</outputDirectory>
                  <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                  <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                  <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: we moved up the configuration, from execution scope to plugin (global) scope.

---

Also note, in the configuration above we kept the execution, which means maven will always execute this plugin goal at each an every `mvn package` invocation. If you don't want this behavior and only expect to use the command line execution, then you can remove the `executions` section at all.

Comment: you guys are great! I can accept your answer in 3 minutes. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[Since Maven 3.3.1 it's also possible](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) (see the note at the very end of Using the executions Tag section):

> Since Maven 3.3.1 this is not the case anymore as you can specify on the command line the execution id for direct plugin goal invocation.

to execute copy-dependencies execution directly not modifying your pom at all:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies@copy-dependencies
```

Note that of the two copy-dependencies separated by @, the former refers to the plugin goal and the latter refers to the execution id. And general direct invocation of an execution is:

```
mvn <plugin-prefix>:<goal>@<execution>
```

See also [accepted answer to almost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816078/7425756)

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that maven defaults to target/dependency when <outputDirectory> doesn't exist (i.e. you made a mistake in directory path).

E.g. I had double slashes in my path in Windows environment (something like c:\\directory\\subdirectory ) and maven without any error just switched to default target/dependency location.

And yes, it's possible to declare the output directory outside of the project (it was my case exactly).