# maven-dependency-plugin ignores outputDirectory configuration

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I want to create a jar file with my main java project and all of it's dependencies. so I created the following plugin definition in the pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

so I execute `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`, it works fine that it copies all the dependencies to `target/dependency` instead of `dependency-jars`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is normal: you configured a special execution of the `maven-dependency-plugin`, named `copy-dependencies`, however, invoking the goal `dependency:copy-dependencies` directly on the command line creates a default execution, which is different than the one you configured. Thus, your configuration isn't taken into account.

In Maven, there are 2 places where you can configure plugins: either for all executions (using `<configuration>` at the `<plugin>` level) or for each execution (using `<configuration>` at the `<execution>` level).

There are several ways to solve your issue:

- Move the `<configuration>` outside of the `<execution>`, and make it general for all executions. You would have:

  ```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
      <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```

  Note that, with this, all executions of the plugin will use this configuration (unless overriden inside a specific execution configuration).
- Execute on the command line a specific execution, i.e. the one you configured. [This is possible since Maven 3.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166538/how-to-execute-maven-plugin-execution-directly-from-command-line) and you would execute

  ```
  mvn dependency:copy-dependencies@copy-dependencies
  ```

  The `@copy-dependencies` is used to refer to the `<id>` of the execution you want to invoke.
- Bind your execution to a specific phase of the Maven lifecycle, and let it be executed with the normal flow of the lifecycle. In your configuration, it is already bound to the `package` phase with `<phase>package</phase>`. So, invoking `mvn clean package` would work and copy your dependencies at the configured location.

Comment: This works just fine, thanks for sharing this solution.