# maven-dependency-plugin usage to download dependency jars

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

Hoping someone can explain how to set the plugin options correctly.

I am looking to have a pom file that someone could execute an `mvn` command on to download all the jars of the dependencies (transitive included) defined in the pom (including their `sources` and `javadoc` jars) from Maven Central and copy them to a specified directory.

My question appears quite similar to [maven-dependency-plugin ignores outputDirectory configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815961/maven-dependency-plugin-ignores-outputdirectory-configuration)  but dwells on a slightly different aspect. Tried the approach advised in the accepted answer there but that didn't work.

pom file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gq.jetstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-download-sources-javadocs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>5.2.22.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>

                <executions>
                   <execution>
                     <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                     <phase>package</phase>
                     <goals>
                       <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                       <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                       <classifier>sources</classifier>
                       <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                       <includeClassifiers>sources,javadoc</includeClassifiers>
                     </configuration>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>
</project>
```

Executing `mvn package` against this pom doesn't do anything. The output for the goal execution was empty.

`Alt 1`: Tried the following command. This copied the `javadoc` jars only and not the binary jars and `sources` jars of the dependencies.

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies@copy-dependencies
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------< gq.jetstream:maven-download-sources-javadocs >------------
[INFO] Building maven-download-sources-javadocs 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) @ maven-download-sources-javadocs ---
[INFO] Copying spring-core-5.2.22.RELEASE-javadoc.jar to C:\projects\code\maven-download-sources-javadocs\target\dependency-jars\spring-core-5.2.22.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
[INFO] Copying spring-jcl-5.2.22.RELEASE-javadoc.jar to C:\projects\code\maven-download-sources-javadocs\target\dependency-jars\spring-jcl-5.2.22.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.846 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-22T02:09:55+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why do you like to copy them to a directory instead of using them? The download is usually simply done by building the project... and most of the time people use a repository manager ... ?

Comment: BTW: Why have you configured that: `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` ???

Comment: We have an environment that is not connected to the internet. We are looking to use this mechanism to enable junior staff to download the jars specified in the pom in one place before copying them using a USB drive to the internal Nexus repo @khmarbaise

Comment: Apologies. `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` is not necessary. I'll remove that.

Comment: That sounds a bit strange to be honest... `jars specified in the pom in one place before copying them using a USB drive to the internal Nexus repo` if you have already a repository manager why is that repo manager not connected to the internet to provide the things you need ... the usage etc. can be controlled by Nexus... The simplest thing I could think of is using the build which downloads all needed thigns and calling `mvn dependency:sources (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html) to get sources... the javadoc is most of the time not needed.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but unfortunately, this is necessaitated because the application environments are air-gapped due to various rules.